# Ganon dom parser and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ganon

I'm trying to include the Ganon dom parser into Codeigniter, but I'm receiving a Non existent class error.

`Non existent class: Ganon`

**Replication instructions:**

1. Download codeigniter
2. Download Ganon and extract into the application/libraries folder
3. Use `$this->load->library('ganon');` in your controller

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: where you place Ganon dom parser library in Codeigniter ?

Comment: From the docs: "Class names and file names must match." If you open up ganon.php you'll notice there is no class named `Ganon`. See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudshark was right,  In this case the main class for Ganon.php was `tokenizer_base`.  I had to rename the file from `ganon.php` to `tokenizer_base.php` and use `$this->load->library('tokenizer_base');` in my controller.  Hope this helps someone else.